# options_from_collection_for_select with tricky label involving another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm creating a form in an admin dashboard where you can change the owner of a company with a HTML select ; sounds simple.

I want to catch the id of all the users (`user.id`) as value of this select, but I want to show their full name which are stored in another table (`user_detail.first_name` and `user_detail.last_name`) associated with the first one.

**Two problem here :**

- How to get the datas of this second table (`user_detail`) from the first one (`user`) with options_from_collection_for_select
- How to mix their first_name with their last_name (NOTE : I've a `full_name` method in my UserDetail model that may be useful here)

Thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your query is to retrieve from db all the users you want to show on the select, but use the `includes` method to retrieve associated data from another table with the query, just like this:

```
@users = User.includes(:user_detail)
# @user.includes(:user_detail).where(...)
```

Then, build the data structure needed for the select_tag:

```
@options_for_select = []
@users.each { |user| @options_for_select.push([user.user_detail.full_name, user.id]) }
```

Finally on the view, use the options_for_select method of select_tag:

```
select_tag :owner, options_for_select(@option_for_select)
```